# line up multiple objects having same data (reduce redundancy)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a web application and i have used **jquery validation** as :

```
$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        emailID: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        pass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        user_pass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        }
    }
```

**everything is working** but the problem is as object `emailID` and `user_email` both are having the **same data** also same for `pass` and `user_pass`, how can i **line them in one** without changing my `name` attribute in html, something like this :

```
$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        emailID, user_email:
        {
            required: true,
            email : true
        }        
    }
```

i know this structure is not correct.

and as i am having **lots of objects** having same data, so it doesnt seems to be good doing the **repetition**

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, the value you pass is a **JavaScript object**.

Comment: @FelixKling now its clear to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function RequiredRule( email, minlength ) {
    this.email = email;
    this.minlength = minlength;
    this.required = true;
}

$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        emailID: new RequiredRule(true),
        pass: new RequiredRule(false, 6),
        user_email: new RequiredRule(true),
        user_pass: new RequiredRule(false, 6)
    }
});
```

Comment: i liked this, let me try .. thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
var one = {
    required: true,
    email: true
},
    two = {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6
};

$("#register").validate({
    rules: {
        emailID: one,
        pass: two,
        user_email: one,
        user_pass: two
    }
});
```